# Pig Get Hour and Minute of Epoch Timestamp in Milliseconds

Tags: apache-pig

I have a column of bytearray epoch timestamps in milliseconds in pig. I was wondering how to get the hour and minute cooresponding to this timestamp.

For example:

```
Hour(1441016271778) = 10
Minute(1441016271778) = 17
```

GetHour and GetMinute from the pig docs isn't working, it produces null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetHour and GetMinute will take DateTime object as input.

**Ref :**

1. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#get-hour
2. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#get-minute

**Input :**

```
1441016271778
```

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'input.csv'  USING  PigStorage(',') AS (epoch_time:long);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE  GetHour(ToDate(epoch_time)) AS hour, GetMinute(ToDate(epoch_time)) AS min;
```

**Output :**

```
(3,17)
```